# need to search all the directory in unix having name cycle_x_work , where x will change everytime the process run

Tags: shell, unix

Informatica runs a process daily and generate folders like cycle_1_work and next day it will generate folder like cycle_2_work .

I need to pick the latest folder and grab all the txt files .

Also any day they can reset the counter and x can start from 1 .

Please help me with this

Comment: you need to write some shell script for this. First use  - ls -t1 cycle_* |  head -n 1 to pickup latest folder. Use file list for better processiing. You can use sequence generator and reset it every time you start a new session. Go and check sequence generator property. if you calculating sequence using some logic then you need to reset it every time using parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in linux bash shell (I assume the folders are generated in a particular directory where the command below can be executed to display the files therein):

> ls  $(ls -ltr | grep ^d | grep "cycle_*_work" | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}')